# Is there a python hamcrest matcher library for performing XML document matching?

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing, xpath, hamcrest

I'm interested in both xpath matching and full document comparisons:

```
assert_that(mydoc, hasTextAtXPath('/foo/bar', 'text'))

assert_that(mydoc, matchesStructurally('<some_xml/>'))
```

Does any matcher library exist for this?  If not, what is the best place to start with for this type of comparison, so that I can write one of my own?

Answer (score 0):

lxml has XPath matching: http://codespeak.net/lxml/

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Python version of Hamcrest](https://github.com/hamcrest/PyHamcrest). It does not currently provide XML matchers. I'd be happy to work on some if you define what you need.

Comment: I'm using said version. What I'm looking for is a matcher that can -- using some basic XML Canonicalization rules analogous to the ones used for WS-Security over in web-services-land -- check that an XML node has identical structure to the matched item.

Also, the ability to check XPath results would be nice, as exemplified in the upper line of code.